# What's my user agent when I parse website with rvest package in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Since it is easy in R, I am using [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) package to parse HTML to extract informations from website.

I am wondering what's my User-Agent (if there is any) during the request, since User-Agent is assigned to the internet browser or is there a way to set it somehow?

My code that open session and extract informations from HTML is below:

```
library(rvest)
se <- html_session( "http://www.wp.pl" ) %>% 
html_nodes("[data-st-area=Glonews-mozaika] li:nth-child(7) a") %>%
html_attr( name = "href" )
```

Comment: Here's a shortcut if you're using any regular linux distribution: run ``netcat -l -p 8080 localhost | grep -i user-agent``, then create ``html_session("http:://localhost:8080")``.

Comment: That's very nice.Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used https://httpbin.org/user-agent to find out:

```
library(rvest)
se <- html_session( "https://httpbin.org/user-agent" )
se$response$request$options$useragent
```

Answer:

```
[1] "libcurl/7.37.1 r-curl/0.9.1 httr/1.0.0"
```

See [this bug report](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/30) for a way to override it.

Comment: Thanks, so I checked this with `se$response$request$opts$useragent`

Comment: If you'll edit your answer with this line: 'se$response$request$opts$useragent' i will accept it :)

Comment: Edited. I needed to use `options` though, not `opts`. Not sure if you had a typo there or if we are using a different library version or something.

Comment: Good response, but the use of https://httpbin.org/user-agent as the example is somewhat misleading, as it implies that this special URL does the magic: in fact, any URL should give the same correct result. http://example.org is a better example, since it is deliberately generic.

Comment: Good point, though if you look at the edit history you'll see that I originally did just use the website's response (`se['response']`).

Answer (score 3):

I found this somewhere in a tutorial, it looks like an easier faster way to do it:

```
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://www.linkedin.com/job/", user_agent(uastring))
```

Comment: For this to work, you'll need **httr** package additionally.