# Web scraping from an HTML table using rvest

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and am trying to scrape the following table:

```
                    <table class="dp-firmantes table table-condensed table->striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>FIRMANTE</th>
                                <th>DISTRITO</th>
                                <th>BLOQUE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td>ROMERO, JUAN CARLOS</td>
                                <td>SALTA</td>
                                <td>JUSTICIALISTA 8 DE OCTUBRE</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>FIORE VIÑUALES, MARIA CRISTINA DEL >VALLE</td>
                            <td>SALTA</td>
                                <td>PARES</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I'm using the rvest package and my code is the following:

```
link <- read_html("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html?")
table <- html_nodes(link, 'table.dp-firmantes table table-condensed table-striped')
```

But when I go to look at the 'table' object in R, I get the following error: {xml_nodeset (0)}

My instinct is that I'm actually not scraping any of the html content from the table, but I don't know how to fix this/why this is occurring. I'm not sure if the error is in my R code, if I'm just using the wrong CSS selector or if maybe this is javascript code and not html? Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Edited: here is the link I'm using
https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html

[Edited: screenshot of the search results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rvTG.png)

Comment: that nodes (table) does not exist on that url

Comment: Kaitlin, the url you provide does not seem to take us to a page with the table you describe. For isntance, in your html table code it seems like the names of the congresspersons endorsing a bill is listed. But the url you provide only lists the bills, but not the congresspersons.

Comment: Are you perhaps refering to tables like the following?
It seems  like only a few bills have these extra links pointing to more information about their legislative proceedings.

http://www.senado.gov.ar/parlamentario/comisiones/verExp/820.18/S/PL
http://www.senado.gov.ar/parlamentario/comisiones/verExp/215.17/S/PR

Comment: So, it doesn't seem like the link shows the tables I'm seeing when I manually navigate the search results. I'm not sure if that means the coding for the tables is faulty? Basically if I use this link: https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/buscador2016-99.html and search all of the bills, the search results page shows the tables with information on legislators who have signed the bills, their districts etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code to parse the "Listado de Autores" tables for those bills that have them. For instance bill with expendiente N. 820/18 (link = http://www.senado.gov.ar/parlamentario/comisiones/verExp/820.18/S/PL) has that table, but I webscraped the first 500 bills and did not find any other bill with such data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html_object <- read_html('http://www.senado.gov.ar/parlamentario/comisiones/verExp/820.18/S/PL')

html_object %>% 
html_node(xpath = "//div[@id = 'Autores']/table") %>% # This is the xpath adress that worked for me. The CSS locator ypu provide did not work.
html_table() %>% as_data_frame() %>% ## Get the html table and store it in a tibble
mutate(X1 = gsub("\\n|\\t|  ", "", X1)) ##Remove the extra line brakes (\\n), tabs (\\t), and spaces ("  ") present in the html table.
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  X1
  <chr>
1 Romero, Juan Carlos
2 Fiore Viñuales, María Cristina Del Valle
```

Edited: Screenshot of Rś html capture thrugh read_html('https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html?pagina=2')

[image]

Comment: This would work but unfortunately I need this information for bills from the Chamber of Deputies as well.

Comment: We will gladly help, but please let us know the URL where we can find them.

Comment: This has been the link I've been using: https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/buscador2016-99.html 

I just searched all of the bills and that's the page where I was referencing the above html table from. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I will need to know what do you input into that form. 
For instance, I inputed in "Tipo de Proyecto" <- "TODO", and in "Cámara de inicio" <- "Diputados" and obtained an html with multiple elements and what seems more than 125thousend projects. I got this message "125456 Proyectos Encontrados"

Comment: I just input "Tipo de Proyecto" Todos and then did not adjust any of the other search features. I have figured out a way to automate the page navigation over the search results using the html_session() and jump_to() functions in the rvest package. But I would like to be able to collect the data in the tables on the search results page that provides the name of the deputy signing the bill, their district and political party, if possible.

Comment: Could you perhaps share a screenshot of the table you are looking for?

Comment: I added the screenshot of the search results to the original post as I was unsure how to add the image to a comment.

Comment: I am sorry, but it will be tricky. The https://www.hcdn.gob.ar server delivers  html code that is browser dependent. This emans that wha you get on your chrome browser is not necesarily the same as what you get from R's httr user agent.

I have added a caption of the html that R sees (in fact, the code that R captured as it is exported into an html file to my hard drive). As you can see, the html R sees lacks part of what you get through chrome.

Comment: It seems to me that you have two options. The first one is to disguise R's user agent to look like chrome. The user agent is a string of text that tells the server which browser you are using. The second answer to this question might help you set a custom usear agent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406503/What%27s%20my%20user%20agent%20when%20I%20parse%20website%20with%20rvest%20package%20in%20R

Comment: The second option is to figure out how the url of each bill page is cosntructed, and scrape each bill page individually.

It seems to me that the URLs follow a basic sequence of number year:

https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp?exp=3505-D-2018
https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp?exp=3506-D-2018
...
https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/proyectoTP.jsp?exp=3556-D-2018

Comment: Wow, that totally worked! I was able to scrape those tables from those pages. I could run a loop that scrapes over each url sequentially by number. Can I ask where you found those pages?

Comment: From here : https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/secparl/dsecretaria/s_t_parlamentario/2018/index.html
Every edition of "Tramite Parlamentario" has the bills listed an linked. For example, this is the 64th 2018 edition: https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/secparl/dsecretaria/s_t_parlamentario/2018/tp_064.html

Comment: Thank you again, those tables were so much easier to scrape!