# cannot download the html file using R download.file and download functions

Tags: r, selenium, web-crawler

The website [here](http://www.shtdsc.com/2016/tdjy/dkxx/crdk/?id=202012702) can be manually downloaded but cannot through download.file and download functions, and also cannot be visited by rselenium.

[image: R cannot download the html file]

[image: Showing blank in rselenium]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: (1) I don't have `download`, just `download.file` ... what package are you using? (It isn't `remotes::download`, that has a different order of args.) (2) The error from `download.file` is your issue, it appears there is a network problem. I periodically get warnings about *"operation timed out"*, so perhaps the web server is flaky or distant. When it doesn't err like that, I get a [202 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202), meaning *"the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed"*. This suggests another API endpoint?

Comment: (3) Your link is different from your text, is that a factor?

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear guidance. (1)The download function is from downloader package which is found [here](https://sites.google.com/a/stanford.edu/rcpedia/screen-scraping/web-scraping-with-r).(2)The network is fine. I used those functions to download other websites and they all worked fine. (3)I think it's not.  The link from question and the link from text have different id parameters but they all have the same problems: cannot be downloaded using R and cannot be visited through rselenium.

Comment: Sure, all three, if that's how you're keeping it. Regardless, (a) intermittent behavior, and (b) 202 response. That latter is indicative of something else going on, perhaps something to do with the API itself. What type of structure are you expecting from this? I can't find rhyme-or-reason from the return as-is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to curl down the tables showing in the webpage. After I manually downloaded the html file to my local file path, I can use following codes  `webpage<-read_html(file_path)`
`content <- webpage%>%html_nodes("div table tbody tr th")%>%html_text()`
to transform them into structured data. I need more than 200 pages like this. If I cannot download them in bulk through R, I have to visit those 200 pages one by one and press ctrl+S repeatedly, which is really tedious.

Comment: I understand your frustration. Is it possible that the webserver detects that you're using a scraper and is [tarpitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) you? Two thoughts: (1) make sure the terms of use allow you to scrape, because if it explicitly says no then my next suggestion is ill-advised (and/or illegal); (2) modify your [`User-Agent` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406678/3358272) to masquerade as a user-based browser. But again, please respect their Terms.

Comment: I'll carefully look at their terms, thank you very much for your help and advice!