# Change user agent when using rvest::read_html

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am able to change the user agent using the `httr` package and create a session with the new user agent. However I am not sure how to use this new user agent with the `read_html` function to get the html document using the defined user agent.

I have seen the bug report [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/30), though unfortunately, it’s still not clear to me how to get this to work once you create a session and then have to use the `read_html` function.

As an example to edit the user agent, I have the below:

```
library(rvest)

link = "https://www.bbc.com/"

my_session = session(link)
my_session$response$request$options$useragent

user_agent_new = user_agent("Test User 1")

my_session2 = session(link, user_agent_new)
my_session2$response$request$options$useragent
```

How do you set the user agent in the `rvest::read_html` call?

Comment: What didn't work with your attempt? Note the assignment for link should be quoted, did you want html_session? And for the linked bug comment, httr is required to be imported.

Comment: What didn't work with your attempt? Note the assignment for link should be quoted, did you want html_session?  For your my_session2 apparently httr needs to be imported as commented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406503/whats-my-user-agent-when-i-parse-website-with-rvest-package-in-r#comment81198678_33250659

Comment: @Qharr I want to use the read_html function to scrape a webpage but with a generic user agent ID rather than the normal one from rvest / httr. I am not sure how to use that function with the user agent being defined differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: `rvest` and `xml2` use `httr` under the hood, so I'll introduce `httr` in my answer here.

As you note in your post, dynamically setting the User Agent is very straightforward when using the `httr` package. As an example I'll use the link you listed above:

```r
library(httr)

# Let's set user agent to a super common one
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"

# Query webpage
bbc <- GET("https://www.bbc.com/",
           user_agent(ua))

# Confirm it's actually used the desired user agent
bbc$request$options$useragent
#> [1] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
```

Now you can compare the User Agent value when using the `httr` defaults:

```r
library(httr)

# Query webpage with default user agent
bbc <- GET("https://www.bbc.com/")

# Print default user agent value
bbc$request$options$useragent
#> [1] "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.2"
```

Obviously, you can set the User Agent to whatever you want. Here is a list of [common User Agents](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/).