# How to include a user_agent in my scraping loop

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, user-agent, httr

I'm trying to scrape prices for multiple products from the same seller, but I wasn't able to read the html through R (error 403). After some research I found out you can surpass this problem by setting a user agent using the `httr` package.

But now as i want to scrape multiple product sites in a loop, i'm not sure how to integrate the `GET` function and the `user_agent` into my loop.
So far my code looks like this:

```
for (j in input_deindeal$`Deindeal Artikel`) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0.25, max=0.5))
  i<-i+1
  vec_deindeal[i] <- try( paste0('https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/',j)%>%
                          read_html %>%
                          html_element('#QuantitySelectorLayout_QuantitySelectorLayout [id$=price]') %>%
                          html_text()%>%
                          str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
                          as.integer())
}
```

(The correct `html_element` and `html_text` are also not set yet, that will probably be a further problem)
j refers to Article ID's from the products on the webshop, e.g. 16030981 and 16030983. So the links look like this: https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/16030981 and https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/16030983

Edit: So far, I tried this but without success:
(Error message: `Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`)

```
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
for (j in input_deindeal$`Deindeal Artikel`) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0.25, max=0.5))
  i<-i+1
  vec_deindeal[i] <- try( GET( paste0('https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/',j,user_agent(ua)))%>%
                          read_html %>%
                          html_element('#QuantitySelectorLayout_QuantitySelectorLayout [id$=price]') %>%
                          html_text()%>%
                          str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
                          as.integer())
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change user agent when using rvest::read\_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975138/change-user-agent-when-using-rvestread-html)

Comment: I also stumbled upon this post and tried to implement it, but i'm not really sure to include the code from the post. I'll edit the question so you can see what I tried so far.

Comment: you have `( )` in wrong place - you have `user_agent(ua)` inside `paste0()` but it should be outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have `)` in wrong place.

You have `user_agent(ua)` inside `paste0()` but it should be outside `paste0()` as second argument in `GET()`

I use spaces to show it:

```r
GET(  paste0('https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/',j),  user_agent(ua)  )
```

or

```r
url <- paste0('https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/',j) 

GET(  url,  user_agent(ua)  )
```

or

```r
paste0('https://www.deindeal.ch/de/product/',j) %>% GET( user_agent(ua) )
```

---

I use page https://httpbin.org/get to test it

without `user_agent()` it shows `"libcurl/7.68.0 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.2"`

```r
> GET( paste0('https://httpbin.org/', 'get') )

Response [https://httpbin.org/get]
  Date: 2022-03-10 17:54
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 373 B
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip, br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "libcurl/7.68.0 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.2", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-622a3b72-00b48f9c2c15da155db2e723"
  }, 
  "origin": "79.163.206.131", 
...
```

with `user_agent()` it shows `"Mozilla/5.0"`

```r
> GET( paste0('https://httpbin.org/', 'get'), user_agent('Mozilla/5.0') )

Response [https://httpbin.org/get]
  Date: 2022-03-10 17:52
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 346 B
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip, br", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-622a3ac6-41ace39e5aa032da3e312de9"
  }, 
  "origin": "79.163.206.131", 
...
```